# Cost of passing IEnumerable with only one element vs passing the element itself

Tags: c#, arrays, parameter-passing

I am developing a data-acquisition system which has some event-based data flows.

Typically, there is the `NewDataAvailableArgs` class, which returns one or more new values.

My doubt is: should I have two different arg classes, like below:

```
class NewManyDataAvailableArgs
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Values { get; private set; }

    public NewDataAvailableClass(IEnumerable<int> values)
    {
        values = Values;
    }
}

class NewSingleDataAvailableArgs
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public NewDataAvailableClass(int value)
    {
        value = Value;
    }
}
```

Or should I stop worrying and just use a collection with a single element in case I have only one value to pass?
I'm afraid, por exemple, that I would end up raising too many events like this, with (possibly unnecessary) creation of a new array only because the constructor signature says so:

```
Something.NewDataAvailable(this, new DataAvailable(new int[] { single_value });
```

Should I prefer a single signature, or this sort of an "overload" of events? Would it be a matter of performance, of style, or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: it should not be a performance matter. The difference is probably unperceptible and do not optimize before you need to

Comment: The solution is up to you, however the problem you will face with making two constructors, and making two classes is the maintenance. Yes, *technically* using a single int instead of an array/IEnumerable is faster. However, not by a noticeable, or even calculable amount, and is it worth the extra *headache* of handling two classes?

Comment: [This article](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/12/08/c-fundamentals-returning-zero-or-one-item-as-ienumerablelttgt.aspx) does not contains answer, but has interesting measure related to IEnumerable with one item

Comment: It's up to you. Perf will be negligible (and you can easily measure it yourself to find out). Personally, I would use a List<> and not worry about the single-case items, unless the single-case item is the main scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do clients care specifically about the fact that there will be a single element or do they just treat the collection the same no matter how many elements there are? A specialized event is only a good idea if there is a consumer that will make use of it. If all the consumer does is foreach over the items and print them there is no use for a special event.

Regarding performance I can imagine that the single-value version can save an allocation but the architectural costs seem high.

Comment: I will accept this because in the end you pointed the right direction: focusing on what the client code needs. Depending on that, either option could be the best one, while there is no "right choice" if we examine only the event classes themselves. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to go here is to use the one case of the IEnumerable since the memory overhead is not that big, there would just be a few extra bytes allocated for the pointer towards the one value you stored. This is a compromise you have to make if you want to fit all the unique flow cases of a collection in a single line. So in short, yes you lose some probably unnoticeable performance, but you gain code readability.